# Why task is unsuccessful for firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to sign in with Firebase. I coded these codes but when I sign in on my app, I take the message from !task.isSuccessful at my code. How can I solve this problem basically? I'm new for the android studio.

I think I could code wrongly in this part when I click sign in button call this function

```
private void createAccount(){
    String email=userEmail.getText().toString();
    String password=userPassword.getText().toString();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).
            addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        //when Authentication is successful
            if (task.isSuccessful()){  
Log.d(TAG,"createUserWithEmail:onComplete"+task.isSuccessful());
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Registration was 
provided",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent signIn= new 
Intent(SignInActivity.this,UserMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(signIn);
            }//when Authentication is failed
             else {
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.
                        this,"Registration is unsuccessful! Please try 
again...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you share your onActivityResult code also

Comment: What does `task.getException().getMessage();` return?

Comment: task.getException().getMessage(); where should I add this code ?